# Google API Plus Login Developer Console

Tags: android, console, google-plus

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tutorial, but did not find `Android` as the type, when i have selected **Installed Application** radio button

I have not found this screen at `Google Developer Console`:

[image]

Comment: why it has been downvote? May i know the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting up a project**
Once you create the project, you need to configure it by editing the Consent screen, and creating one or more OAuth2 client IDs.

**Setting up the consent screen**
The consent screen is shown to the users whenever your application requests access to their data. You can access it from APIs & auth => Consent screen from the left hand navigation tree.

[image]

and then

[image]

Check out **How to create OAuth2 client id and secret** [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/wiki/How-to-create-OAuth2-client-id-and-secret) for detailed and step by step information...

Answer (score 0):

I get this pop-up when I go to "APIs & Auth"->"Credentials
"[image: screeny]